# Avoid overwriting mongodb documents with partially loaded entity from morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

[Morphia](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/) supports [ignoring fields](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#ignoring-fields) of loaded documents which can reduce the amount of data running over the wire when retrieving large documents significantly. There's a drawback tough: When loading a partial object, writing the same object back to mongoDB will overwrite any existing fields with empty values.

Is there a native morphia way to detect if a mongodb object was loaded partially, so one can avoid the overwriting scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Datastore.merge()` rather than `Datastore.save()`.